# Angular states - resolve before exiting

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My Angular app includes a main screen and several tabs and I'm using `$stateProvider` to switch between states. Whenever I'm leaving a tab (=state) I must perform an asynchronous operation. I would like to wait for that operation to complete before actually moving to the new tab. Somewhat like `resolve` that is done when leaving the state rather than entering.

How can this be achieved?

**Example snippet:**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('myproject.main', {
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: '...',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('myproject.tabs.a', {
        url: '/tab_a',
        controller: 'TabACtrl',
        templateUrl: '...',
        onExit: doSave
    })
    .state('myproject.tabs.b', {
        url: '/tab_b',
        controller: 'TabBCtrl',
        templateUrl: '...',
        onExit: doSave
    });

function doSave(MyService) {
    return MyService.save(); //async, promise
}
```

Here I wanted to save (async) whenever switching between the tabs. However when entering the main state from a tab, I want to be sure that save has finished (doing the save on `myproject.main`'s onEnter/resolve is not good for me).

**Problem**: when entering `myproject.main` (MainCtrl), the async MyService.save() operation is still processing. I want it to be completed/resolved.

I tried to hack it with the following piece of code, but it **does not work** - the state change enters a loop

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, MyService){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(ev, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        if (toState.name === 'myproject.main' && //switching to main
            fromState.name && //for a certain tab
            fromParams.resume !== true ) {

              ev.preventDefault(); //stop the state change
              //do the save and then continue with the state change
              MyService.save().then(function(){
                $state.go(toState, {resume: true}) //continue with a "resume" parameter
              });
        }
    });             
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: It should only `preventDefault()` and run `MyService.save()` if there are unsaved changes. That way you won't get into any loop.

Comment: @HankScorpio sure, this logic is clear, but at the moment I have no way to know whether there are unsaved changes so I'm looking for another solution

Comment: If you're working with a `<form>` angular provides the $dirty flag to tell you if the user has modified any of the fields.

Comment: By the way, there's a bug in your code there. I think `fromParams.id !== 'resume'` should say `fromParams.resume !== true`.